# Another Hibernate MappingException Repeated column in mapping for entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-mapping

I searched, but did not found any of thoose problems, that i have.
It is an other hibernate MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity

I have some entities that I want to map. AbstractReaction has a protected String: text. Every sub-entities have to make custom getter and setter methods for that.
The relevant code:

The AbstractReaction:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class AbstractReaction extends LongId {
    protected String text;

    public abstract String getText();

    public abstract void setText(String text);
    ...
}
```

The ImageReaction:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "image_reaction")
public class ImageReaction extends AbstractReaction {
    ...
    @Override
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 2000)
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "text", length = 2000)
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
    ...
}
```

The LinkReaction:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "link_reaction")
public class LinkReaction extends AbstractReaction {
    ...
    @Override
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 2048)
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "text", length = 2048)
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

At spring entityManagerFactory creation, i get the following exception:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1225)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:853)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.projectaim.model.entity.reaction.ImageReaction column: text (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:709)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:731)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:753)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:506)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass.validate(SingleTableSubclass.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1358)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1849)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    ... 49 more
```

How should I manage 'text' in an object oriented way, to avoid this exception?

Comment: Your mapping really makes no sense: you have two distinct properties, mapped to the same column of the same table, and that unique column should have a max size of 2000 in one case, and 2048 in the other case. Just put th mapping in the base class, and remove the getters and setters from the subclasses.

Comment: Yeah, that is an acceptable solution. And probably i will do the validation before the DB insert. Thx